# JQuery asmx debugging help needed

Tags: jquery, web-services, asmx

I would appreciate any help I can get with this please. In my local dev, I am able to test this successfully, but I moved the same code to another machine and it does not seem to be working, and debugging is hard on the remote as well. All the code ought to do is send data to the server for processing, but for some reason, this is not working at all. All I have on the server end is a skeleton method to get whatever data is sent and spit it back out but for some reason, the client end spits back an error each time, the code below is executed.

**"There was an error processing the request."**

```
function getusersbyselectedrole() {
                alert(role_filter);//check to be sure data is being collected 
                alert("{role :\"" + role_filter + "\"}"); //check to be sure the ride data is being sent to serve
                alert("<%= ReportsLink %>/LoadUsersByRole");//check to be sure the right service address is being used
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                    url: "<%= ReportsLink %>/LoadUsersByRole",
                    data: "{role :" + role_filter + "}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $("#<%= sUsers.ClientID %>").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "-1").text("select user"));
                        $.each(msg, function(key, value) {
                            $("#<%= sUsers.ClientID %>").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value));
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(res, status) {
                        if (status === "error") {
                            // errorMessage can be an object with 3 string properties: ExceptionType, Message and StackTrace
                            var errorMessage = $.parseJSON(res.responseText);
                            alert(errorMessage.Message);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you told us what the error is =)

Comment: Is there a live link we could see? Are the ajax requests sent to a server on a different domain?

Comment: "There was an error processing the request." . No live links. Just that the code above does not seem to hit the server successfully

Comment: Same domain. I mean there are other requests for data from the same server that work fine. Just that the requests sending data TO the server dont seem to work at all

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying this to IIS 6?  If so, the problem is that the request doesn't have any mapping to ASP.NET.  You could either fix the problem in IIS 6 (see below), or just add .asmx to your URL.  It should already be mapped to web service calls (unless you are using MVC in which case you would have to add .asmx to your routing rules).

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx

Comment: The link to the Service, that is generated, already includes the asmx reference  "/Reports/ReportService.asmx/LoadUsersByRole"

Comment: Do you get any errors in your IIS log?  Also, what version of IIS are you running? Are you running IIS in dev or the dev webserver?

Comment: There are no errors in my IIS log. I suspect the problem could be in the above code as I am also able to add a button, and have it directly call the method on the server(without client code).